# Domain Change, Lost Access to SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server

We recently underwent a domain change and now I seem to no longer have the ability to do anything in SQLEXPRESS. I can connect to it with SQL Server Management Studio, but I cannot access any of the databases therein, and I can't make any changes to any settings. It keeps telling me that I do not have permission to do the things that I am trying to do.

How can I set my new domain login as the owner again so that I can get access to my databases in SQLEXPRESS?

**UPDATE:** I did not use the suggestion below to solve my problem, but while investigating the recommendation, I determined that a local version of the old domain profile still existed on my machine. Fortunately, this profile held all of the same rights as the old one did, so I was able to log in to that and set my new profile as sysadmin.

From there it was a simple task to update ownership on my databases with 'EXEC sp_changedbowner [*new_profile*]' in sqlcmd and I am back in business.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, SQL Express instances include the BUILTIN/Administrator role on the machine in the sysadmin group on the server.  If your old domain account was in that group, but your new domain account is not, that could cause the issue you are seeing.

Try having your new domain account put in the local server Administrators group.

Comment: If this is the case, would it not be easier if this was the case to log into the system with Administrator and then connect with Window Auth on SMS and modify to include new domain?

Comment: @ColdT sure - that would work also.  Either way, the change in the domain of his account is the culprit.  More than one way to skin the cat.